# reset after a merge has conflicted many files

Tags: git

```
git version 1.8.3.1
```

Hello,

I have just merged my local with the repository and now my files have many conflicts.

Normally, when I merge I always do it like this:

```
git merge origin/dev --no-commit --no-ff
```

And if there is many conflicts I would do a:

```
git reset --hard
```

However, this time I got lazy and didn't do the --no-commit --no-ff.

Is there anyway to reset? As what I wanted to do was keep their changes.

```
git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs origin/dev
```

Many thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git won't commit if there are conflicts.  `git reset --hard` should still work fine.

And FYI, it accepts an argument: `git reset --hard COMMIT` will forcibly point your branch at `COMMIT` and make your working directory and index match.  It just happens to default to `HEAD`, the last commit on the branch.